# R/markdown: rendering html tags inside table

Tags: html, r, markdown, tibble, kable

I want to create some sort of html-tag cheatsheet in [R] using markdown. I thought this would be a good idea as I could easily show the tag and the result. Turns out it is not that easy. Let's reframe the sentence: I think it should be easy, but still I am stuck when it comes to printing the results. I would really appreciate some hints :)

What I am doing right now:

````
    ---
    title: "HTML Cheatsheet"
    output: html_document
    ---
    
    ```{r, results="asis"}
    
    # init
    "%>%" <- magrittr::"%>%"
    
    # create table
    tbl <- dplyr::tibble(
        "TAG"="<h1></h1>",
        "EXAMPLE"="<h1>Headline</h1>",
        "RESULT"=cat("<h1>Headline</h1>"))
    
    # print table
    tbl %>%
        knitr::kable() %>%
        kableExtra::kable_styling()
    
    ```
````

My approah does not work. I think it's because `cat("<h1>Headline</h1>")` is printed directely and ruins the tibble. Probably there is a super easy solution to the problem. Unfortunately I am missing the right words to search for answers to my problem (the only results I get is 'how to print html tables in markdown')

Thanks for your expertise :)

Comment: I think you need `knitr::kable(escape = FALSE)` instead

Comment: perfect ... almost ... now the RESULT part is displayed as it should be ... unfortunately the EXAMPLE part is also rendered :D

Comment: lol .. I really had a bad day ... your solution works like a charm. The only thing I had to do was to escape the tags I wanted to show up as "code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

As nate mentioned, I had to use `knitr::kable(escape=FALSE)` to render the html tags. To keep the tags in non rendered form in the EXAMPLE column the only thing I had to do was escape them manually.

````
    ---
    title: "HTML Cheatsheet"
    output: html_document
    ---
    
    ```{r, results="asis"}
    
    # init
    "%>%" <- magrittr::"%>%"
    
    # create table
    tbl <- dplyr::tibble(
        "TAG"="<h1></h1>",
        "EXAMPLE"="\\<h1\\>Headline\\</h1\\>",
        "RESULT"=cat("<h1>Headline</h1>"))
    
    # print table
    tbl %>%
        knitr::kable(escape=FALSE) %>%
        kableExtra::kable_styling()
    
    ```
````